# `npm start` not working for my create-react-app application. Missing template?

Tags: reactjs, npm, npm-install, create-react-app

I typically just run `npm start` for my create-react-app project but after I restarted my computer I can no longer do it and get this weird error:

```
module.js:341
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module './Template'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:290:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:16:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/richardbustos/Google Drive/workspace/portfolio/node_modules/webpack/lib/MainTemplate.js:8:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:422:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:357:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:314:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:367:17)

npm ERR! Darwin 14.5.0
npm ERR! argv "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "start"
npm ERR! node v5.5.0
npm ERR! npm  v4.1.2
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! portfolio@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the portfolio@0.1.0 start script 'react-scripts start'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the portfolio package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     react-scripts start
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs portfolio
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls portfolio
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I tried running `npm install` and updating npm and npde but nothing worked

Comment: i think the issue is somewhere in the project u r trying to import `./Template`, and its failing because the path is not proper, check that.

Comment: Try to sync your npm and node version with the boilerplate

Answer (score 2):

Ahh found a fix. All i had to do was:

```
rm -rf node_module
```

to clean then ran

```
npm install
```

That seemed to work =)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue running the npm start command.

Installing the npm version 4.6.1 helped me solve the problem. I hope it is helpful for some of you.